# Как удалить самое длинное слово из строки?

Tags: c, строки

Мой код на месте длинного слова оставляет пробелы, нужно как-то от них избавиться.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 81

int main()
{
  char str[N];
  int i, j, l, ml, beg, strsize, k;

  clrscr();

  gets(str);

  strsize = strlen(str);

  ml = 0;
  beg = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
  {
    if (!isspace(str[i])) l++;
    else {
      if(l > ml){
      ml = l;
      beg = i - ml;
      }
      l = 0;
    }
  }

  if(l > ml)
  {
   ml = l;
   beg = i - ml;
  }

  ml += beg;

  for(i = beg; i < ml; i++) putchar(str[i]);

  printf("\n");

  i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < strsize; i++)
  {
     for(k = beg; k < ml; k++){
     str[k] = str[k + 1];

     }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < strsize; i++) putchar(str[i]);

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В рамках вашего подхода* - вот измененный фрагмент:

```
printf("\n");
while(str[beg++] = str[ml++]);
strsize = beg-1;
for (i = 0; i < strsize; i++) putchar(str[i]);
```

Надо ли убирать лишние пробелы (и если да, то какие - слева, справа) - смотрите сами.

Еще - обнулите в самом начале переменную `l` и никогда не используйте `gets` - ее больше нет!!